# Italian permesso di soggiorno expired for 2 years

Tags: italy, study

Kindly advise. I made the mistake of not renewing my *permesso di soggiorno* for students for 2 years. I had a huge school fee balance and I couldn't renew without showing exams, which required me clearing the fee balance that had accumulated.

I worked and managed to pay the fee in full, and I have done exams - only 2 exams and my thesis remain. The problem is that I now want to try to renew, but I'm scared. Could anyone advise me on what to do?
I understand I'm in a huge mess. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: Is your permesso expired?

Answer (score 3):

If your permesso is expired, you are actually **overstaying**.

Doing anything to your file may raise *alarm bells*, and get you kicked out of the country/deported. Also, overstaying for that long is REALLY BAD for your immigration future in most countries.

It is crucial you contact an immigration lawyer for advice

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. I will for sure contact a lawyer. Because I just to finish my studies and move back home. My intention is not to live here.

Comment: @kate Doing anything without a lawyer specializing in immigration law is a recipe for absolute disaster in your case

Comment: Thank you very much.